# Не видит библиотеку (C++\CLI)

Tags: c++

Нужно воспроизвести видео.
Для этого был установлен DXSDK.
В классе пишу библиотеку

```
using namespace Microsoft::DirectX::AudioVideoPlayback;
```

Но её не видно. Что не так?

Comment: @vaddemgen, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.
___

А ссылку на библиотеку к проекту вы конечно же подключить не забыли?

Comment: @vaddemgen: Что значит «не видно»? Какие ошибки вы получаете? Может, вы забыли подключить assembly microsoft.directx.audiovideoplayback.dll к проекту?

Comment: Правой кнопкой мыши по проекту, в выпадающем списке жмете Add, затем eferences, в появившемся окне выбираете необходимую библиотеку.

Comment: @VladD, в Microsoft нет DirectX.

Comment: @vaddemgen: Ы?

Comment: @DreamChild, проблема в том сто такой ссылки нет в Framework
____

@VladD, Error: 'DirectX': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type

Comment: @vaddemgen: Ага, проблема с компиляцией, а не с компоновкой. :) Скорее всего, вы таки не подключили assembly. Подключайте.

Вот вам картинка:

![картинка][http://spiderinnet.typepad.com/.a/6a013489b64e31970c015432f8a9f4970c-800wi]